# Meteor User profile undefined error during iron router's logout

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using Meteor.user().profile in helper. When i do logout, i gets error profile undefined. My code below:

```
Template.listedWork.helpers({
  workList: function() {
    if (Meteor.user().profile.yetki == 1) {
      return Work.find({})
    } else {
      return Work.find({
        username: Meteor.user().username
      });
    }

  }
});
```

I'm doing logout in listedWork page for example: localhost/listedWork. That is iron router render code

```
    Router.route('/listedWork', {
      action: function() {
          this.render('listedWork');
      },
    onBeforeAction: function() {

    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      this.layout("loginLayout");
      this.render('login');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  }


     });
```

When i logout here, Meteor.user().profile is call by workList that's why i get this error.

login template render in onBeforeAction for logout. Why listedWork template helper call this here.

Thank you for all helps.

Comment: you could redirect the logged out user to another route instead of continuing  on with the /listedWork action - up to you what route but one suggestion is the log in screen with a message that the user has been logged out.

Comment: Problem is not about the render, it's about Template.listedWork.helpers().  When logout, listedWork is not render but listedWork.helpers is working. Do  you  think it's about iron-router's own mistake or Template's?

Comment: No you don't want to run the action at all if users logged out so redirect and abandon the route thereby not running your helper at all

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I got it ,cant be render there bcs of meteor.user reactive  and helpers re-run which i use. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Meteor.user().profile is undefined after logout is because you no longer have a Meteor.user().  You need to check for this in your helper and do an appropriate action if Meteor.user() returns null.

```
Template.listedWork.helpers({
    workList() {
        if( !Meteor.user() ) {
            // Handle the case.  Redirect to /login or something.
        }
        else {
            // Your current helper code here.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok. listedWork  contains  this helpers. Why helpers  calls in spite of listedwork  dont render?

Comment: Are you logging out while on the listedWork page, or logging out on a different page and then navigating there?

Comment: logging out while on the listedWork page  but  there is no Meteor.userid() so 
It must be stopped at onbeforeaction ? I mean is that it dont need to render others?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I got it ,cant be render there bcs of meteor.user reactive  and helpers re-run which i use.